# Regex does not work in application, yet it works on websites

Tags: c#

I'm using regex to validate if the value enter by user is a valid one.

```
string value = "500,21";
bool is_valid = Regex.IsMatch(value, "/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{2,2})?$/");
```

This piece of code should accept values like:

```
500.21
500,21
```

Yet it gives error saying that it ain't a valid value.

However, when using websites like https://www.regextester.com/ or https://regex101.com/ my regex works perfectly as you can see in here https://regex101.com/r/s6Cl9I/1

Comment: remove those `/`s

Comment: When testing regular expressions on websites make sure they support the engine that .Net uses.  Not all regular expressions engines are the same.

Comment: @L.B thanks, worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward slashes are JavaScript's way of indicating the boundaries of a Regular Expression, much the same way that double-quotes indicate the boundaries of a string. For example, the following two expressions in JavaScript are equivalent:

```
/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{2,2})?$/.test("500,21")

new RegExp("^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{2,2})?$").test("500,21")
```

Online Regex testers will often add those forward-slashes for you because they're thinking in a JavaScript context. But they're not actually part of the Regular Expression itself.

In C#, you're passing the regular expression as a string, so those slashes aren't necessary.

```
string value = "500,21";
bool is_valid = Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{2,2})?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

C# does not like the /'s at the beginning and end of your expression. Regex engines can have different formats and special characters, so watch out for that!